# How do I align grouped inputs with non-grouped inputs in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that has labels and inputs. One input has an group addon. I'm trying to figure out how to align this with the rest of the inputs. The code goes like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="first-input">Some label here</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
           <input name="first-input" class="form-control"><input type="hidden" value="some value">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="second-input">Some label here</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10 input-group">
            <span class="input"
            <input name="second-input" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="third-input">Some label here</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
           <input name="third-input" class="form-control"><input type="hidden" value="some value">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<!--#second-input together with the <span> addon is indented to the left-->
```

I've been trying to align the second input but have not been able to do so.

Comment: You missed the span closing tag

Comment: <span class="input">